# Highchart Relow of Charts Lags in React Grid Layout

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts, react-grid-layout

I'm using the React Grid Layout module for rendering multiple grid cards each containing a chart rendered using highchart.

The cards are arranged in a vertical layout format. On the right side of the cards, there is a side panel to render some other content. When I toggle the side panel the grid cards and the side panel opens and shrink at the the same time but the charts rendered inside the grid cards get resized a bit late which looks bad.

Minimal example setup code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highchart-resizing-forked-jwx5xy

Is there a way to resize all the elements at same time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Edit - 1

Here is the data passed to Highchart
[image]

Comment: Hi @Papu Kumar, How exactly do you want the chart to behave? Is there a way to get the target width of the grid container during animation?

Comment: @ppotaczek Yeah I'm passing a prop called cardConfig which contains the width and height of the grid

Comment: Yes, but it's the current one for each animation step. We don't want to update the chart in each step, that's why I'm asking about the target width. We would be able to run an independent animation for the chart only.